# In MDX how do I do a group by count(*) for a given dimension?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, mdx

In T-SQL I would just use a group by clause and a count(*) in the select statement to give me the value I need.  But with cubes it's different, because the count isn't just over rows, but dimensional combinations.  So I've googled for an answer to no avail.  Here is a detailed explanation of my problem:

My original MDX is:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Measures].[Budget]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Location].[Category - Entity - Facility].[Facility].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Location].[Category - Facility - Unit].[Location].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Calendar].[Day].[Day].ALLMEMBERS
    } ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Location].[Category - Entity - Facility].[Category].&[3]} ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
        [Calendar].[Year  -  Quarter -  Month -  Day].[Day].&[2012-01-01T00:00:00]
      : [Calendar].[Year  -  Quarter -  Month -  Day].[Day].&[2012-05-31T00:00:00]
    ON COLUMNS
    FROM [PHI Census]
  )
)

Results look like this:
    Facility 1    Location 1    Day 1    100
    Facility 1    Location 1    Day 2    100
    Facility 1    Location 1    Day 3    100
    Facility 1    Location 1    Day 4    100
    Facility 1    Location 2    Day 1    80
    Facility 1    Location 2    Day 2    80
    Facility 1    Location 2    Day 3    80
    Facility 2    Location 1    Day 1    65
    Facility 2    Location 1    Day 2    65
    Facility 2    Location 1    Day 3    65
    Facility 2    Location 1    Day 4    65
    Facility 2    Location 2    Day 1    73
    Facility 2    Location 2    Day 2    73
    Facility 2    Location 2    Day 3    73
```

This gives me the [Budget] listed once for each Facility-Location-Day combination.  I would like to remove [Calendar].[Day].[Day].ALLMEMBERS from the ON ROWS clause and simply use a calculate member that would return the count of the number of days for each Facility-Location combination along with each row.  So basically,

```
The results would look like this:
    Facility      Location      Budget   DayCount
    Facility 1    Location 1    100      4
    Facility 1    Location 2    80       3
    Facility 2    Location 1    65       4
    Facility 2    Location 2    73       3
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression of DayCount could be:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[DayCount] AS Count(NonEmpty([Calendar].[Day].[Day].ALLMEMBERS, [Measures].[Budget]))
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but it doesn't give me the results I'm expecting.  For example, I have one facility that has 1 location for 121 days, and two other locations each for 31 days.  I'd expect to see three rows, with 121 in the DayCount of the first, and 31 in the DayCount for the other two.  What I am seeing is 16 rows for my first location, and 2 rows each for my other locations, and each row has a different total for DayCount.

Comment: Perhaps it is not counting days based on the date range that I have defined in the FROM...?

Comment: The days that are not in your sub select are excluded. You can check this with this expression: ``SetToStr([Calendar].[Day].[Day].ALLMEMBERS)``. You can try to replace your sub select with a Where close.